# MSXML memory management

Tags: memory, msxml

I am using COM and XML parser provided by Microsoft to parse some 20 XML files. The application also uses the API provided by the libraries to parse the XML document.

The MSXML3.0 parser seems to be consuming huge amount of memory for cache (garbage collection). Even the the concept of garbage is to refer the same XML document in cache if any future reference are there, but here it again loads the same XML ducument multiple times which  inturn increase the memory usage of my application.

I also tried to debug with DevPartner tool and it does not seems to help me out of this. Because it does not shows any memory leak for this but the memory usage in the task manager keeps on increasing.

I came to know about the garbage collection from the below link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304227

It tells to disable the garbage collection by changing the redit entry 'NoFullGC' and i followed this to fnd this key but i was not able to find it. I even can't find the MSXML3.0 in the regedit.

The another thing that i find weird about this, is that, the memory allocated by this process got freed once i minimize the application window. (this is very much weird to me).

Please help me out of this.

Comment: The another thing that i find weird about this, is that, the memory allocated by this process got freed once i minimize the application window. (this is very much weird to me).

Comment: You're looking at the 'working set' which is emptied by Windows when you minimize a window.  It's generally better to look at the 'Commit Size' number (or 'VM Size' in XP and earlier) which is how much memory you asked for (the working set is how much Windows gave you).

Answer (score 1):

GC does not mean memory leak. Thus memory diagnostic tools cannot not help here - or it must be a false alarm.

In order to mitigate the memory consumption of GC, you may want to:

- Switch to [XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752838%28VS.85%29.aspx) if possible. It is available in all supported Windows.
- Try to force GC with DllCanUnloadNow as specified in the KB article.

I am not sure how minimizing window can kick off GC, but that must has kicked off GC so that memory is recycled afterwards.